# Attribute in CORBA interface - gave errors after server compilation

Tags: exception, corba

It's me again having trouble with CORBA. I just wanted to write some example interface in CORBA where the interface would have one attribute.

Here's my idl file:

```
interface Interfface
{
    readonly attribute double number;

    exception myOwnException {
        string reason;
    };

    void ffunction(in double arg) raises (myOwnException);
    double getNumber();
    void setNumber(in double number);
};
```

My implementation of the IDL interface:

```
#include "interface.hh"

class Implementation : public POA_Interfface
{
    private :
        double number;

    public :
        virtual void ffunction(double arg);
        virtual double getNumber();
        virtual void setNumber(double number);
};

#include "implementation.h"

void Implementation::ffunction(double arg)
{
    this->number = 0;
    arg++;
    throw Interfface::myOwnException("Sth went terribly wrong!");
}

void Implementation::setNumber(double number){
    this->number = number;
}

double Implementation::getNumber(){
    return this->number;
}
```

When I compile interface.idl, implementation.h, implementation.cpp it's ok. The problem is when I want to compile my server.cpp :

```
#include "implementation.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <omniORB4/CORBA.h>
#include <omniORB4/Naming.hh>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    try {
        // init ORB
        CORBA::ORB_ptr orb = CORBA::ORB_init(argc, argv);

        // init POA
        CORBA::Object_var poa_obj = orb->resolve_initial_references("RootPOA");
        PortableServer::POA_var poa = PortableServer::POA::_narrow(poa_obj);
        PortableServer::POAManager_var manager = poa->the_POAManager();

        // create service
        Implementation * service = new Implementation;

        // register within the naming service
        try {
            CORBA::Object_var ns_obj = orb->resolve_initial_references("NameService");
            if (!CORBA::is_nil(ns_obj)) {
                CosNaming::NamingContext_ptr nc = CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow(ns_obj);
                CosNaming::Name name;
                name.length(1);
                name[0].id = CORBA::string_dup("TestServer");
                name[0].kind = CORBA::string_dup("");
                nc->rebind(name, service->_this());
                cout << "Server is running ..." << endl;
            }
        } catch (CosNaming::NamingContext::NotFound &) {
            cerr << "not found" << endl;
        } catch (CosNaming::NamingContext::InvalidName &) {
            cerr << "invalid name" << endl;
        } catch (CosNaming::NamingContext::CannotProceed &) {
            cerr << "cannot proceed" << endl;
        }

        // run
        manager->activate();
        orb->run();

        // clean up
        delete service;

        // quit
        orb->destroy();
    } catch (CORBA::UNKNOWN) {
        cerr << "unknown exception" << endl;
    } catch (CORBA::SystemException &) {
        cerr << "system exception" << endl;
    }
}
```

It gives me errors:

> server.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’: server.cpp:20: error:
>   cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Implementation’
>   implementation.h:4: note:   because the following virtual functions
>   are pure within ‘Implementation’: interface.hh:197: note:     virtual
>   CORBA::Double _impl_Interfface::number()

It seems that CORBA treats my 'number' attribute like a function, not an attribute, am I right? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By declaring an attribute number you get automatically a number() accessor and setting which you both have to implement in your servant. You don't need to define a getNumber() and setNumber() in your IDL, just remove the readonly tag from the attribute to also have the setter.

Just see the attribute as something that automatically generates a setter and a getter which are remotely accessible.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I definded "number" as readonly attribute, because I wanted it to be private in my interface (private field number in my interface). Is it possible? As You wrote, I removed "readonly" declaration but still got error: http://pastie.org/private/ljgn3ekaumcvijj6j3z79w

Comment: By adding an attribute in IDL it is accessible remotely. By removing readonly you have to also implement the setter. If you want to have them completely private, remove the attributes from IDL and just add them as class members in your implementation.